# Change amchart bullet placement using inputs

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Say I have an amchart lineWithScrollAndZoom graph.  I want to allow a user to change a bullet point location on the y-axis by letting them click the bullet point, then they can use a dropdown input or some other input form to allow them to change the y-axis value.  The bullet point and corresponding lines would then change based on where the bullet point was moved.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can use the [clickGraphItem](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCoordinateChart#clickGraphItem) listener to get the data point. And the manipulate the data provider depending on your changes. (e.g. move the current point by changing the date value) Mind that amCharts needs sorted data, so you have to resort it if needed!

Comment: Are there any tutorials on what clickGrahItem can do and how it works?

Comment: Sry for the delay. I made a simple demo using the event. Just take a look at the code. ;) [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gd0v8hbx/)